# Mint 17 Cinnamon: suddenly everything looks messed up

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, theme

I'm kind of freaked out right now. Hopefully I can find a solution here. Something really strange happened.

Basically, all of a sudden, everything started to look messed up. The gui applications remind me of the classic theme in windows. All kinds of effects are gone. The gnome terminal has a black font on its black background. A custom profile I have in it has messed up colors too (it's black on white, it's supposed to be white on black).

I've seen similar questions on the internet, but the proposed solutions have been unsatisfying.
I've tried various things:

- Rebooting
- Changing the theme to something else and then back
- Clearing my cinnamon & gnome settings
- Creating a new user
- Installing official drivers for my video card (I hadn't done that yet)

... but all to no avail.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Everything looks older and white and the font is black]
[image: Another good example]
[image: A terminal, there's actually text in it, it's nearly invisible]

Comment: "I'm a complete newbie to linux." And with a day of experience, decided to change the visual theme. Don't do that; for reals. I've been using Ubuntu since April 2005 and other unixes for 20 years prior to that, I've never had a plug=in theme behave all 3 times I even bothered. True, I didn't give much effort, because they should need any. Switch back to default and learn about the system before you try to make it look coolz.

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about, I didn't change anything about the theme (except after things got messed up, as I tried to fix things). Unless you're talking about the terminal profile. I really needed it to make my console based roguelike games playable though. :D

Comment: You changed nothing about the theme, but then you did change the theme. You've given us incomplete information as to what might have caused the problem. That's forgivable for a newbie. I'd reload the system from scratch and not touch any setting and see if that allows you play rogue (which was a bit too important to me in times past, too :)

Comment: Well... after some more screwing around, I ended up botching the entire system. So I had to start over from scratch anyway, haha. I'll try to avoid touching the sensitive parts this time, and see what gives!