# Cinnamon messed up

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, appearance

I'm using Linux Mint 17 with Cinnamon (2.2). After I closed an unresponsive PDF viewer, Cinnamon's appearnce got messed up. Now windows' title bar looks like Win 98/95. If it might be of use, I compiled GTK+ 3.12 yesterday, but till today everything was fine. I also have GTK+ 3.10 (didn't remove it). How can I fix this problem? I reinstalled Cinnamon, but that did not help.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: computer (nemo)]

[image: desktop]

[image: themes]

Comment: Looks as if you changed default theme.

Comment: @jimmij yes, but I did that long time ago, and it was fine

Comment: btw, it doesn't make any difference if I change the theme

Comment: Did you try to change theme for something different, and then switch back?

Comment: yep, didn't help

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160435/mint-17-cinnamon-suddenly-everything-looks-messed-up

Comment: yes, ran into that question ealier, but there is no answer for that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the cause for the mess: It was **the new (compiled) version of GTK+** (3.12). Because I already had another GTK+ 3 (3.10.8), the new version had some conflicts. So to fix the problem, I just removed the compiled version of GTK+. You can do it either of the following ways:

First way (of uninstalling a compiled program (in this case GTK+)):
1. Download the tarball (the compressed file) of GTK+ 3.12 or whatever version you compiled and installed last
2. Extract it
3. Go to the directory and run ./configure and then make uninstall

Second Way:
Install `checkinstall` tiny tool using your favorite package manager, download the tarball of GTK+ (the version you installed last), extract it, got to the extracted directory, run `./configure`, then run `make checkinstall`. This will supposedly create a .deb package (or a .rpm, depending on your distro) that tracks all the changes to your local system, so the package can be easily and completely uninstalled using a package manager or just apt-get.